# java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, classcastexception

I used java mail API for receiving mails from gmail and download the attachments from mail and store it into a folder. If I send a mail without attachments it is working, if I send it with an attachment it's giving the following error.

Error:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'watsonapp.ReadMail$EmailAttachmentReceiver.downloadEmailAttachments:135'
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart
at watsonapp.ReadMail$EmailAttachmentReceiver.downloadEmailAttachments(ReadMail.java:135)`
```

And my code is here:

```
String contentType = message.getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";

                // store attachment file name, separated by comma
                String attachFiles = "";


                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                  // javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart multiPart =    (javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
                     Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                            part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                    }
                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                        || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                    Object content = message.getContent();
                    if (content != null) {
                        messageContent = content.toString();
                                //toString();   
                    }
                }

                // print out details of each message
                System.out.println("Message --->" + (i + 1) + ":");
               // System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
                System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
                System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
                //System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent().toString());
                System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
                System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
                //System.out.println("\t Unread Messages:"+ Folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
            }

            // disconnect
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`
```

Comment: This is likely a classloader issue but without a lot more detail on how the application was built, the server it's running on and the versions of the libraries in use it is impossible to debug.

Comment: And why is (what appears to be the correct code) commented out?

Comment: Make sure you have only one copy of the javax.mail.* classes in your class path, and if you're running on a Java EE application server make sure you have no javax.mail.* classes packaged with your application.

Comment: BillShannon can you explain a bit clear please.